# Getting objects from an Array

Tags: jquery

I may be doing this very badly but I'm new to this!
if I have an array that contains objects like this

```
var company = [H7 = {companyName:"company1"},F4 = {companyName:"company2"}]
```

If I get a reference as a string say "F4" is there any way I can go

```
myCompName = company "F4" companyName and get the result "company2"
```

I was trying to use inArray like this

```
myStand = $.inArray("F4", companyObjects)
myCompName = companyObjects[myStand].companyName
```

but this doesn't work and yet

```
myStand = $.inArray(F4, companyObjects)
myCompName = companyObjects[myStand].companyName
```

does work. Do I have my array set up wrong or is there a way to do this?
Thank you
Alex

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are indexed by numbers what you actually do with this line

```
var company = [H7 = {companyName:"company1"},F4 = {companyName:"company2"}]
```

is this:

```
H7 = {companyName:"company1"}
F4 = {companyName:"company2"}
var company = [H7,F4]
```

if you want to access H7 and F4 you need to create another object:

```
var company = {H7: {companyName:"company1"},F4: {companyName:"company2"}};
```

and then you can do this:

```
$.each(company, function(i, comp) {
   var myCompName = 'company "' + i + '" companyName and get the result "'+
        comp['companyName'] + '"';
});
```

or

```
company['H7']['companyName']
```

or

```
company.H7.companyName
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this way, http://jsfiddle.net/CBxMt/?

Basically company variable is an object that holds your company data. You can still access elements with [] notation just like arrays.